# Android Split string for comma

Tags: android

I've this string:

```
1,Diego Maradona,Footballer,Argentina
```

I need manipulate and split this string for this output for set the textView:

```
1
Diego Maradona
Footballer
Argentina
```

I tried this method:

```
String phrase = "1,Diego Maradona,Footballer,Argentina";
String delims = "[,]";
String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims);
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(tokens[i]));
```

But the output is last value of the string, why?:

```
Argentina
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using `setText()` which replaces the previous content, so you're seeing just the last item. Use `.append()` instead, this way you'll be able to see all the entries.

Comment: Okay, `textView.append(tokens[i] + "\n");` output is correct! Thanks!

Comment: You will probably want to add commas below each entry, except on the last item of your list. I'll let you that as an exercise :-) Once you're done, both for reputation and feedback for other users, you should accept the answer that helped you most (that is, selecting the 'tick' under the points of the answer that helped you most).